# How do properties work when storing objects?

Tags: c#, oop, properties

In C#, properties when used with primitive types seem fairly simple. For example, on an integer, with the following property:

```
private int _foo = 9;

public int Foo 
{
    get 
    {
        return _foo;
    }
    set
    {
        _foo = value;
    }
}
```

it is pretty easy to figure out that when the user types, say, `int bar = Foo` would return the value of _foo,  and assign it to the variable bar. Likewise, `Foo = 10`, the backing field, _foo's, value is changed to 10. However, this becomes more complicated when objects (not referring to c#'s `object` keyword) are stored in properties, which can have methods. For instance:

```
public class Sample 
{
    private int NoGoodName

    public Sample() {}

    public void Method1() 
    {
        NoGoodName *= 2;
    }
}

public Sample TestSample {get; set;}
```

If the user were to call, say, TestSample.Method1(), what exactly would happen? Would it call the getter, and then call Method1 on the returned value, or would it call Method1() first and then set TestSample to the result?

Comment: When the property is not a value type and it is a reference type (object), the property returns a reference to the object and then the method is called on that object being referenced by the reference. Think about it like a rope wherein one end is tied to the object and the other end can be passed around (or you can have many ropes but they are all tied to the same object). So when you access the property, the rope is passed to you and now you can communicate (call methods) with the object via the rope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would call the getter, then call `Method1`.

This is due to the fact that the [`.` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operator) is left associative. An expression like `x.y.z` is always evaluated from the left to right. It also makes logical sense. The left operand (`TestSample`) needs to be evaluated before calling the method, or else how would the runtime know on which instance to call the method?

If you are having trouble getting the idea of getters and setters around your head. Try imagining getting a property as calling a `Get...` method and setting a property as calling a `Set...` method. For example:

```
GetTestSample().Method1(); // TestSample.Method1()
SetSomeValue(10); // SomeValue = 10;
```

That might make it clearer for you.